# Problema al desinstalar Netbeans 8.2 en Windows 10

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8.2

Bueno estoy intentando desinstalar el netbeans 8.2 porque ya no me ejecutaba el IDE para volver hacer una instalación limpia. Pero al momento de ejecutarse el asistente de desinstalacion me da un mensaje sobre el componente "nb-base /8.2.0.0.201610071157" el cual no fue encontrado y se cierra el asistente de desinstalacion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, pero después de borrar la carpeta .nbi, pruebo a desinstalar el programa y me vuelve a crear la carpeta saliéndome el mismo error.
¿Alguna solución? Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2):

para poder realizar la desinstalación deberías borrar esa carpeta que en mi caso utilizando Windows 10 la tengo en la siguiente dirección:

**C:\Users\TuUsuario\.nbi\product-cache\nb-base\8.2.0.0.201609300101**

Te recomiendo directamente borrar la carpeta .nbi completamente

PD: para poder ver esta carpeta debes en el mismo explorador de archivos entrar a Archivos->Opciones de Carpeta, solapa Ver y tildar la opción "Mostrar archivos, carpetas y unidades ocultos".

Saludos y espero que te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me sirvio!

Comment: Cuando elimino la carpeta vuelve a crearse y no he podido desinstalar...